# If two elliptic functions share the same poles and zeros (including multiciplity) then they are proportional

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions, meromorphic-functions

I’m trying to understand the following statement found on my lecture notes:

> If two elliptic functions share the same poles and zeros (including
> multiciplity) then they are proportional

I’m trying to reason the following way: if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not constant, they must be meromorphic (since holomorphic elliptic functions are constant). Then they can be written as a rational function of two polynomials. I could now write the denominator and numerator of each of them as a product of linear factors (right?).

So $f_i=g_i/h_i$ where the zeros of $g_i$ are the zeros of $f_i$ and the zeros of $h_i$ are the poles of $f_i$. Finally, if $f_1$ and $f_2$ have the same zeros and poles then their numerators and denominators can only differ by a multiplicative constant respectively. Is that correct?

Comment: Why not just show that the ratio of elliptic functions (with respect to the same lattice action) is elliptic and observe that the ratio of these two functions is holomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A meromorphic function on $\Bbb{C}$ can't be globally written as a ratio of two polynomials in general. This is true if the meromorphic function has at worst a pole at infinity, but otherwise false. Also, since elliptic functions are biperiodic with respect to a rank $2$ lattice action, they have infinitely many poles (by the result you cite) so that if $e(z) = p_1(z)/p_2(z)$ were the expression of some elliptic function as a ratio of polynomials, it would follow that $e(z)$ has finitely many poles corresponding to the vanishing locus of $p_2(z)$.

Anyway, I'll suggest a few ways to see this:

As I mentioned in the comments, if you believe that an entire elliptic function is constant, then just note that a ratio of meromorphic functions $f_1,f_2$ with identical poles and zeros gives a global holomorphic function $f_1/f_2$ (after extending over removable discontinuities). Then, any condition of the form $f_i(z+\omega) = f_i(z)$ for $i=1,2$ is still satisfied by $f_1(z)/f_2(z)$.

Alternatively, here is a proof without assuming the fact about entire elliptic functions: $g = f_1/f_2$ extends (over some removable discontinuities) to a holomorphic function on all of $\Bbb{C}$. On the other hand, because $f_1$ and $f_2$ are periodic with respect to a rank $2$ lattice $\Lambda$ (by definition of being elliptic), $\lvert g(z)\rvert \le C$, where $C = \max\{g(z):z\in \overline{\Omega}\}$, where $\Omega$ is a fundamental domain for the $\Lambda$-action. Therefore, $g$ is an entire bounded function and hence constant by Liouville's theorem. So, $f_1(z) = \lambda f_2(z)$ for all $z$ and for some $\lambda \in \Bbb{C}$.

Alternatively, as elliptic functions correspond to meromorphic functions on a complex torus $\Bbb{C}/\Lambda$, it follows that they must have poles somewhere or else be constant, since a holomorphic function defined everywhere on a compact Riemann surface is constant.